# Azure module installation in Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to install azure module but it is showing the error
"unable to download the list of available providers, Check your internet connection.

Comment: check your connection, check you proxy settings?

Comment: Are you trying from a corp net?  If so your firewall team may be blocking this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings and your firewall rule to be sure everything is working fine. If not working, you could download the module to your local computer and import it to the powershell.

```
Import-Module c:\windows\uyhe.ps1
```

Ensure the Execution-Policy is RemoteSigned

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Hope this helps